# how to animate the individual items in items control

Tags: windows-phone-7

```
<Canvas x:Name="MainPageCanvas"> 
    <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"> 
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate> 
                <Canvas x:Name="MainPageCanvas2"> 
                    <TextBlock x:Name="MainPageTextBox" Text="{Binding LineThree}" Canvas.Left="{Binding LineOne}" Canvas.Top="{Binding LineTwo}" FontSize="32" >  
                    </TextBlock> 

                    <TextBlock x:Name="MainPageTextBox2" Text="{Binding LineFour}" Canvas.Left="{Binding LineOne}" Canvas.Top="{Binding LineTwo}" FontSize="32"/> 
                </Canvas> 
            </DataTemplate> 
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl> 
</Canvas>
```

How do apply animations to the textblocks within the items Control and the animations should begin based on a event

Answer (score 0):

See this [blog post I wrote on re-creating the metro-style sliding of elements](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/03/metro-in-motion-fluid-list-animation/) in a list as a Pivot control moves from one item to the next.

You need locate the container that hosts the Canvas elements created by your template. Then iterate over those which are visible, applying your animation:

```
      // locate the stack panel that hosts the items
      VirtualizingStackPanel vsp = list.Descendants<VirtualizingStackPanel>().First()
                                                  as VirtualizingStackPanel;

      // iterate over each of the items in view
      int firstVisibleItem = (int)vsp.VerticalOffset;
      int visibleItemCount = (int)vsp.ViewportHeight;
      for (int index = firstVisibleItem; index <= firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount; index++)
      {
        var lbi = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (lbi == null)
          continue;

        // add your animation here!
      };
```